# Grails war packaging error when using custom AssetFile based on angular-template-asset-pipeline

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin, grails-2.5

On a Grails 2.5.6 project I'm having trouble writing a custom asset-pipeline AssetFile / Processor pair for Angular template processing. More specifically, it works when I run in develop mode (`grails run-app`), but fails when packaging (`grails war`).

The new AssetFile is a simple customization of angular-template-asset-pipeline 2.2.7 (I need to use a new parameter that was only added on the new version of the plugin, only for Grails 3).

For reference, here are the files:

- AngularTemplateAssetFile: https://ideone.com/eyuJVi (on src/groovy)
- asset.specs: https://ideone.com/iGuUJv (on web-app/META-INF/asset-pipeline/asset.specs)

I put the following code on Bootstrap.groovy:

```
if (!AssetHelper.assetSpecs.contains(AngularTemplateAssetFile)) {
    AssetHelper.assetSpecs << AngularTemplateAssetFile
}
```

on _Events.groovy:

```
eventAssetPrecompileStart = { assetConfig ->
    assetConfig.specs << 'vtp.angular.AngularTemplateAssetFile'
}
```

On `grails run-app` the processor is called correctly and the angular templates are processed and injected on the page. On `grails run-war`, I get the following error:

```
 ...
.
|Compiling 7 GSP files for package [vtpWeb]
..
|Compiling 2 GSP files for package [springSecurityCore]
.
|Compiling 8 GSP files for package [jodaTime]
.
|Compiling 4 GSP files for package [mail]
.
|Compiling 1 GSP file for package [greenmail]
.
|Compiling 5 GSP files for package [console]
..
|Building WAR file
...................................................................................................
|Precompiling Assets!
.Error
|
WAR packaging error: vtp.angular.AngularTemplateAssetFile
```

The message just contains the class name, and I could not figure out how to debug the application when it is building the war.

Versions used:

- Grails 2.5.6
- asset-pipeline: 2.6.7
- Original version of `angular-template-asset-pipeline` used as base for my fork: 2.2.7

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Not yet! Still investigating